# How to access a span in a class but i can not change the html File

Tags: html, css

I have a Question in regards to CSS. I have a given Layout and can only writte CSS comands to access the given html text to style it.

The Problem is the span that i try to access has no Id or is in a class. The html tree is consistant throughout the whole html File. So if i can access this specific span it should change all spans who are aranged in the file.

I am by all means no CSS expert but i tried it with first-child etc. but it didnt work.
Here a picture:[image: I need to access the thing in the blue circle]

If someone who has more expiriance in this topic would help me, i would appriciate it very much.
Steven

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful selector in this situation could be the adjecent sibling selector:

```
#FzBoard_Image_1232 + span {...}
```

Keep in mind you can select the image before the span however you like and it doesnt have to be by class, a simple `img + span` would work but youre risking selecting more elements in the document so its always good to make it as specific as possible

Alternatively this could work too:

```
span.ui-button-text > span:first-of-type {..}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you access that span

```
#FzBoard_1232 .ui-button-text span:first-of-type {
  /* ...... */
}
```

**#FzBoard** has an ID and its the parent element of the parent element of that span so you access the span by its parents.

You can also try .ui-button-text span but its not specific and it will apply to other spans as well if the have the same parent selector

Comment: The Problem is that the id isnt consistant because the number fluktuate. The number behind is the persons database id... and in CSS you cant do stuff with variables i guess as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: @StevenTumler check out my updated info

Comment: If I understand right the issue with multiple spans being selected is that withing the .ui-button-text there are multiple spans

Comment: Yes, and i meant the span without an id. I tried to circle it. Its the span in the .ui-button-text class without an id. This span is present in multiple spans with the same class. So i need a css comando who can consistant filter out this span in the whole dokument..

Comment: By the way with this selector #FzBoard_1232 .ui-button-text span you are accessing only one item which had an ID then you go through its childs until you reach that span

Comment: No you are not, there are multiple spans that are children of the `#FzBoard_1232 .ui-button-text`

Comment: Blye you are right i missed that, so he can access to that specific span by add :first-of-type to the selector

Comment: @StevenTumler do you want to apply ur styles to all similar spans or only this one?, because you mentioned that id is not consistent, am assuming that you have other similar spans as wll